# why `_exit` has an underscore prefix while other system calls don't have?

Tags: c, linux

I'm new to C and Linux, just a question on system calls:
[image]
so why `_exit` has an underscore prefix while others don't have?

Comment: Probably to avoid confusion with the standard library call? :/

Comment: There's a history of using leading underscore for library-internal functions, since user programs are not supposed to use them.  So `_exit` was presumably the "internal" version of `exit`, which did the actual exiting via the OS after cleanup and `atexit()` functions had been run.  But it turned out to be useful to be able to call `_exit()` directly if you wanted to bypass the cleanup, and eventually it became standardized.  That's my guess, anyway.

Comment: The close reason doesn't make sense to me.  The question seems perfectly clear and well-focused.

Answer (score 3):

The system call `_exit` is so named to differentiate it from the library function `exit`.

Programs should in most cases use the `exit` library call to terminate the process.  This function calls any `atexit` handlers that were registered before calling `_exit` internally which actually terminates the process.